# How to wrap an element with a link override it events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got 2 elements that i want to wrap and cancel their events. one is iframe and the other is an object ..

```
   <a href="http://google.com">
<iframe src="http://pldaflix.com/video/54312" width="500" height="415" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</a>


     <a href="http://google.com">
<object height="400" width="500"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="false">
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="movie" value="http://embed.rede.com/player/">
<param name="FlashVars" value="id=97219&&autostart=false">
<embed src="http://embed.rube" allowfullscreen="false" AllowScriptAccess="always"
flashvars="autostart=false" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="400" width="500" /></object>

</a>
```

I want to override their events with html or css, instead of using javacript.. but javascript option is also an option..

How do I override the event of the object and the iframe with the event of the link?

UPDATE:

I thought to do something like this:

```
        <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
        <a href="http://google.com">
        <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 9999; background-color:blue;">
            <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
                <iframe src="http://playflix.com/video/54312" width="500" height="415" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Put the div of the iframe below the div of the link..

doesnt work .. but i think the solution should be along those lines

An alternative way would be to use javascript to disable click on the div

**UPDATE:**

I need a simple solution. the solution is to put the div above the iframe

Comment: You mean you want *any* click on the object and iframe to activate the link instead of whatever is inside?

Comment: I want to have my own link to be activated..and not what is inside hte iframe object. see update

Answer (score 0):

assuming jQuery:

```
$("iframe").click(function(){
   window.location = <yourDesiredHref>;
});
```

same applies for the object.

Comment: hmmm.. javascript could have been a better solution.. but okay, i will try so.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd alternatively you can place an overlay over the object and iframe.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd http://jsfiddle.net/Jv7Gx/2/ It works. Try clicking on the text not covered and then click on the text where it is covered.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the link cover the object by putting it before the object and giving it an absolute position. See fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/BP9xc/4/

The important bits are:

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="overlay" href="http://google.com"></a>
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="500" height="415" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and styling it so the link covers the object:

```
.container{
    position:relative; 
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#overlay{
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: doesnt work.. to be honest.. if you that iframe was a working div..it wouldnt override it

Answer (score 0):

With html/css you could try something like this:

- create an empty div "overlay" beneath the object
- make it as high as the iframe and object combined (815px if you don't use any padding/margin)
- make it as wide as the bigger element (500px)
- position it so that it overlays the other elements, for example with `margin-top:-500px;`
  give it a `display:block;` and a bigger `z-index` than the other two elements just to be sure it's on top
- put a link in there/around it that stretches as big as "overlay" is

You could also try if it's possible to put "overlay" around the elements and putting it on top with `z-index` then.

Comment: I tried he z-index, as you can see in my example.. it didnt work